# Filesystem search class in C#

Tags: c#, performance, file-system, search, windows

Anyone can tell how to make this code faster?
This search takes too much time... 700 000 files for 15 minutes...
I will be grateful for each micro optimization!

Search Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class FindFile
{
    private static readonly char[] InvalidFilePathChars;
    private static readonly char[] InvalidFilePatternChars;
    static FindFile()
    {
        InvalidFilePathChars = Path.GetInvalidPathChars();
        List<char> set = new List<char>(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
        set.Remove('*');
        set.Remove('?');
        InvalidFilePatternChars = set.ToArray();
    }
    // Enumerates the files directly in the directory specified
    public static void FilesIn(string directory, Action<FileFoundEventArgs> e)
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile(directory, STAR, false, false, true);
        ff.FileFound = (o, a) => e(a);
        ff.Find();
    }
    //Enumerates the folders directly in the directory specified
    public static void FoldersIn(string directory, Action<FileFoundEventArgs> e)
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile(directory, STAR, false, true, false);
        ff.FileFound = (o, a) => e(a);
        ff.Find();
    }
    //Enumerates the files and folders directly in the directory specified
    public static void FilesAndFoldersIn(string directory, Action<FileFoundEventArgs> e)
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile(directory, STAR, false, true, true);
        ff.FileFound = (o, a) => e(a);
        ff.Find();
    }
    //Enumerates the files anywhere under the directory specified
    public static void AllFilesIn(string directory, Action<FileFoundEventArgs> e)
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile(directory, STAR, true, false, true);
        ff.FileFound = (o, a) => e(a);
        ff.Find();
    }
    //Enumerates the folders anywhere under the directory specified
    public static void AllFoldersIn(string directory, Action<FileFoundEventArgs> e)
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile(directory, STAR, true, true, false);
        ff.FileFound = (o, a) => e(a);
        ff.Find();
    }
    //Enumerates the files and folders anywhere under the directory specified
    public static void AllFilesAndFoldersIn(string directory, Action<FileFoundEventArgs> e)
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile(directory, STAR, true, true, true);
        ff.FileFound = (o, a) => e(a);
        ff.Find();
    }
    #region Kernel32
    internal static class Kernel32
    {
        internal const int MAX_PATH = 260;
        internal const int MAX_ALTERNATE = 14;
        internal const int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2;
        internal const int ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND = 3;
        internal const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct FILETIME
        {
            public uint dwLowDateTime;
            public uint dwHighDateTime;

            public DateTime ToDateTimeUtc()
            {
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(dwLowDateTime | ((long)dwHighDateTime << 32));
            }
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
        {
            public FileAttributes dwFileAttributes;
            public FILETIME ftCreationTime;
            public FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
            public FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
            public uint nFileSizeHigh; //changed all to uint from int, otherwise you run into unexpected overflow
            public uint nFileSizeLow;
            private uint dwReserved0;
            private uint dwReserved1;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
            public char[] cFileName;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_ALTERNATE)]
            private char[] cAlternateFileName;

            public bool IgnoredByName
            {
                get
                {
                    return
                        (cFileName[0] == ZERO) ||
                        (cFileName[0] == '.' && cFileName[1] == ZERO) ||
                        (cFileName[0] == '.' && cFileName[1] == '.' && cFileName[2] == ZERO);
                }
            }
        }

        public enum FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS
        {
            FindExInfoStandard = 0,
            FindExInfoBasic = 1
        }

        public enum FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS
        {
            FindExSearchNameMatch = 0,
            FindExSearchLimitToDirectories = 1,
            FindExSearchLimitToDevices = 2
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum FINDEX_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS
        {
            FindFirstExCaseSensitive = 1,
            FindFirstExLargeFetch = 2,
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFileEx(
            IntPtr lpFileName,
            FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS fInfoLevelId,
            out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData,
            FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS fSearchOp,
            IntPtr lpSearchFilter,
            FINDEX_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS dwAdditionalFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool FindNextFile(IntPtr hFindFile, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr hFindFile);
    }
    #endregion

    public struct Info
    {
        //Returns the parent folder's full path
        public string ParentPath { get { return Path.GetDirectoryName(FullPath); } }
        //Gets or sets the full path of the file or folder
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
        //Returns the file or folder name (with extension)
        public string Name { get { return Path.GetFileName(FullPath); } }
        //Returns the extenion or String.Empty
        public string Extension { get { return Path.GetExtension(FullPath); } }
        //Returns the UNC path to the parent folder
        public string ParentPathUnc { get { return (FullPath.StartsWith(@"\\")) ? ParentPath : (UncPrefix + ParentPath); } }
        //Returns the UNC path to the file or folder
        public string FullPathUnc { get { return (FullPath.StartsWith(@"\\")) ? FullPath : (UncPrefix + FullPath); } }
        //Gets or sets the length in bytes
        public long Length { get; set; }
        //Gets or sets the file or folder attributes
        public FileAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
        //Gets or sets the file or folder CreationTime in Utc
        public DateTime CreationTimeUtc { get; set; }
        //Gets or sets the file or folder LastAccessTime in Utc
        public DateTime LastAccessTimeUtc { get; set; }
        //Gets or sets the file or folder LastWriteTime in Utc
        public DateTime LastWriteTimeUtc { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Win32FindData
    {
        public char[] Buffer;
        public IntPtr BufferAddress;
        public Kernel32.WIN32_FIND_DATA Value;
    }

    // Provides access to the file or folder information durring enumeration, DO NOT keep a reference to this
    // class as it's meaning will change durring enumeration.

    public sealed class FileFoundEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly Win32FindData _ff;
        private int _uncPrefixLength;
        private int _parentNameLength;
        private int _itemNameLength;
        private bool _cancelEnumeration;

        internal FileFoundEventArgs(Win32FindData ff)
        {
            _ff = ff;
        }

        internal void SetNameOffsets(int uncPrefixLength, int parentIx, int itemIx)
        {
            _parentNameLength = parentIx;
            _itemNameLength = itemIx;
            _uncPrefixLength = uncPrefixLength;
        }

        //Returns the parent folder's full path
        public string ParentPath { get { return new String(_ff.Buffer, _uncPrefixLength, _parentNameLength - _uncPrefixLength); } }
        //Returns the UNC path to the parent folder
        public string ParentPathUnc { get { return new String(_ff.Buffer, 0, _parentNameLength); } }
        //Gets the full path of the file or folder
        public string FullPath { get { return new String(_ff.Buffer, _uncPrefixLength, _itemNameLength - _uncPrefixLength); } }
        //Returns the UNC path to the file or folder
        public string FullPathUnc { get { return new String(_ff.Buffer, 0, _itemNameLength); } }
        //Returns the file or folder name (with extension)
        public string Name { get { return new String(_ff.Buffer, _parentNameLength, _itemNameLength - _parentNameLength); } }
        //Returns the extenion or String.Empty
        public string Extension
        {
            get
            {
                for (int ix = _itemNameLength; ix > _parentNameLength; --ix)
                    if (_ff.Buffer[ix] == '.')
                        return new String(_ff.Buffer, ix, _itemNameLength - ix);
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        //Gets the length in bytes
        public long Length { get { return _ff.Value.nFileSizeLow | ((long)_ff.Value.nFileSizeHigh << 32); } }
        //Gets the file or folder attributes
        public FileAttributes Attributes { get { return _ff.Value.dwFileAttributes; } }
        //Gets the file or folder CreationTime in Utc
        public DateTime CreationTimeUtc { get { return _ff.Value.ftCreationTime.ToDateTimeUtc(); } }
        //Gets the file or folder LastAccessTime in Utc
        public DateTime LastAccessTimeUtc { get { return _ff.Value.ftLastAccessTime.ToDateTimeUtc(); } }
        //Gets the file or folder LastWriteTime in Utc
        public DateTime LastWriteTimeUtc { get { return _ff.Value.ftLastWriteTime.ToDateTimeUtc(); } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is ReadOnly
        public bool IsReadOnly { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) != 0; } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is Hidden
        public bool IsHidden { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0; } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is System
        public bool IsSystem { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != 0; } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is Directory
        public bool IsDirectory { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) != 0; } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is ReparsePoint
        public bool IsReparsePoint { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != 0; } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is Compressed
        public bool IsCompressed { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.Compressed) != 0; } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is Offline
        public bool IsOffline { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.Offline) != 0; } }
        //Returns true if the file or folder is Encrypted
        public bool IsEncrypted { get { return (Attributes & FileAttributes.Encrypted) != 0; } }
        // Captures the current state as a <see cref="FindFile.Info"/> structure.

        public Info GetInfo()
        {
            return new Info
            {
                FullPath = FullPath,
                Length = Length,
                Attributes = Attributes,
                CreationTimeUtc = CreationTimeUtc,
                LastAccessTimeUtc = LastAccessTimeUtc,
                LastWriteTimeUtc = LastWriteTimeUtc,
            };
        }
        //Gets or sets the Cancel flag to abort the current enumeration
        public bool CancelEnumeration
        {
            get { return _cancelEnumeration; }
            set { _cancelEnumeration = value; }
        }
    }

    private const string STAR = "*";
    private const char SLASH = '\\';
    private const char ZERO = '\0';
    //Returns the Unc path prefix used
    public const string UncPrefix = @"\\?\";

    private readonly Win32FindData _ff;

    private char[] _fpattern;
    private int _baseOffset;
    private bool _recursive;
    private bool _includeFolders;
    private bool _includeFiles;
    private bool _isUncPath;
    //Creates a FindFile instance.
    public FindFile() : this(UncPrefix, STAR, true, true, true) { }
    //Creates a FindFile instance.
    public FindFile(string rootDirectory) : this(rootDirectory, STAR, true, true, true) { }
    //Creates a FindFile instance.
    public FindFile(string rootDirectory, string filePattern) : this(rootDirectory, filePattern, true, true, true) { }
    //Creates a FindFile instance.
    public FindFile(string rootDirectory, string filePattern, bool recursive) : this(rootDirectory, filePattern, recursive, true, true) { }
    //Creates a FindFile instance.
    public FindFile(string rootDirectory, string filePattern, bool recursive, bool includeFolders) : this(rootDirectory, filePattern, recursive, includeFolders, true) { }
    //Creates a FindFile instance.
    public FindFile(string rootDirectory, string filePattern, bool recursive, bool includeFolders, bool includeFiles)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rootDirectory) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePattern))
            throw new ArgumentException();

        _ff = new Win32FindData();
        _ff.BufferAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
        _ff.Buffer = new char[0x1000];
        _ff.Value = new Kernel32.WIN32_FIND_DATA();

        _recursive = recursive;
        _includeFolders = includeFolders;
        _includeFiles = includeFiles;

        BaseDirectory = rootDirectory;
        FilePattern = filePattern;
    }
    // The event-handler to raise when a file or folder is found
    public event EventHandler<FileFoundEventArgs> FileFound;
    // Gets or sets the maximum number of allowed characters in a complete path, default = 4kb

    public int MaxPath
    {
        get { return _ff.Buffer.Length; }
        set { Array.Resize(ref _ff.Buffer, Check.InRange(value, Kernel32.MAX_PATH, 0x100000)); }
    }
    private int UncPrefixLength { get { return _isUncPath ? 4 : 0; } }
    //Gets or sets the base directory to search within
    public string BaseDirectory
    {
        get { return new String(_ff.Buffer, UncPrefixLength, _baseOffset - UncPrefixLength); }
        set
        {
            if (value.IndexOfAny(InvalidFilePathChars) > 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid characters in path.");

            if (!value.StartsWith(@"\\"))
                value = UncPrefix + value;
            if (!value.EndsWith(@"\"))
                value += @"\";

            _isUncPath = value.StartsWith(UncPrefix);
            value.CopyTo(0, _ff.Buffer, 0, _baseOffset = value.Length);
        }
    }
    // Gets or sets the file pattern to match while enumerating files and folders.

    public string FilePattern
    {
        get { return new String(_fpattern); }
        set
        {
            if (value.IndexOfAny(InvalidFilePatternChars) >= 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid characters in pattern");
            _fpattern = value.TrimStart(SLASH).ToCharArray();
        }
    }
    //Gets or sets the Recursive flag
    public bool Recursive { get { return _recursive; } set { _recursive = value; } }
    //Gets or sets the IncludeFiles flag
    public bool IncludeFiles { get { return _includeFiles; } set { _includeFiles = value; } }
    //Gets or sets the IncludeFolders flag
    public bool IncludeFolders { get { return _includeFolders; } set { _includeFolders = value; } }
    //Gets or sets the RaiseOnAccessDenied flag, when set to true an 'Access Denied' can be raised
    public bool RaiseOnAccessDenied { get; set; }
    //Performs the search raising the FileFound event for each entry matching the request
    public void Find(string pattern)
    {
        FilePattern = pattern;
        Find();
    }
    //Performs the search raising the FileFound event for each entry matching the request
    public void Find()
    {
        Check.NotNull(FileFound);
        GCHandle hdl = GCHandle.Alloc(_ff.Buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            FileFoundEventArgs args = new FileFoundEventArgs(_ff);
            _ff.BufferAddress = hdl.AddrOfPinnedObject();

            FindFileEx(args, _baseOffset);
        }
        finally
        {
            _ff.BufferAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
            hdl.Free();
        }
    }

    private bool IsWild()
    {
        return (_fpattern.Length == 1 && _fpattern[0] == '*')
               ||
               (_fpattern.Length == 3 && _fpattern[0] == '*' && _fpattern[1] == '.' && _fpattern[2] == '*');
    }

    private void FindFileEx(FileFoundEventArgs args, int slength)
    {
        Kernel32.FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS findInfoLevel = Kernel32.FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoStandard;
        Kernel32.FINDEX_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS additionalFlags = 0;

        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
        {
            //Ignore short-names
            findInfoLevel = Kernel32.FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS.FindExInfoBasic;
            //Use large fetch table
            additionalFlags = Kernel32.FINDEX_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS.FindFirstExLargeFetch;
        }

        _fpattern.CopyTo(_ff.Buffer, slength);
        _ff.Buffer[slength + _fpattern.Length] = ZERO;

        IntPtr hFile = Kernel32.FindFirstFileEx(
            _ff.BufferAddress,
            findInfoLevel,
            out _ff.Value,
            Kernel32.FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS.FindExSearchNameMatch,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            additionalFlags);

        if ((IntPtr.Size == 4 && hFile.ToInt32() == -1) ||
            (IntPtr.Size == 8 && hFile.ToInt64() == -1L))
        {
            Win32Error(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            return;
        }

        bool traverseDirs = _recursive && IsWild();

        try
        {
            do
            {
                int sposition = slength;
                for (int ix = 0; ix < Kernel32.MAX_PATH && sposition < _ff.Buffer.Length && _ff.Value.cFileName[ix] != 0; ++ix)
                    _ff.Buffer[sposition++] = _ff.Value.cFileName[ix];

                if (sposition == _ff.Buffer.Length)
                    throw new PathTooLongException();

                if (!_ff.Value.IgnoredByName)
                {
                    bool isDirectory = (_ff.Value.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;

                    if ((_includeFolders && isDirectory) || (_includeFiles && !isDirectory))
                    {
                        args.SetNameOffsets(UncPrefixLength, slength, sposition);
                        FileFound(this, args);
                    }
                    if (traverseDirs && isDirectory)
                    {
                        _ff.Buffer[sposition++] = SLASH;
                        FindFileEx(args, sposition);
                    }
                }
            } while (!args.CancelEnumeration && Kernel32.FindNextFile(hFile, out _ff.Value));
        }
        finally
        {
            Kernel32.FindClose(hFile);
        }

        // Recursive search for patterns other than '*' and '*.*' requires we enum directories again
        if (_recursive && !traverseDirs)
        {
            _ff.Buffer[slength] = '*';
            _ff.Buffer[slength + 1] = ZERO;

            hFile = Kernel32.FindFirstFileEx(
                _ff.BufferAddress,
                findInfoLevel,
                out _ff.Value,
                Kernel32.FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS.FindExSearchNameMatch,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                additionalFlags);

            if ((IntPtr.Size == 4 && hFile.ToInt32() == -1) || (IntPtr.Size == 8 && hFile.ToInt64() == -1L))
            {
                Win32Error(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                do
                {
                    int sposition = slength;
                    for (int ix = 0; ix < Kernel32.MAX_PATH && sposition < _ff.Buffer.Length && _ff.Value.cFileName[ix] != 0; ++ix)
                        _ff.Buffer[sposition++] = _ff.Value.cFileName[ix];

                    if (sposition == _ff.Buffer.Length)
                        throw new PathTooLongException();

                    if (!_ff.Value.IgnoredByName)
                    {
                        bool isDirectory = (_ff.Value.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory;
                        if (isDirectory)
                        {
                            _ff.Buffer[sposition++] = SLASH;
                            FindFileEx(args, sposition);
                        }
                    }
                } while (!args.CancelEnumeration && Kernel32.FindNextFile(hFile, out _ff.Value));
            }
            finally
            {
                Kernel32.FindClose(hFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Win32Error(int errorCode)
    {
        switch (errorCode)
        {
            case Kernel32.ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
            case Kernel32.ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND:
                return;
            case Kernel32.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
                if (!RaiseOnAccessDenied) return;
                goto default;
            default:
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Check Class:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
static partial class Check
{
    public static void Assert<TException>(bool condition) where TException : Exception, new()
    {
        if (!condition)
            throw new TException();
    }

    public static void Assert<TException>(bool condition, string message) where TException : Exception, new()
    {
        if (!condition)
        {
            ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(TException).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            if (ci != null)
            {
                TException e = (TException)ci.Invoke(new object[] { message });
                throw e;
            }
            throw new TException();
        }
    }

    public delegate Exception ExceptionBuilder();

    public static void Assert(bool condition, ExceptionBuilder fnExceptionBuilder)
    {
        if (!condition)
            throw fnExceptionBuilder();
    }

    public static void Assert<TException>(bool condition, string message, Exception innerException) where TException : Exception, new()
    {
        if (!condition)
        {
            ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(TException).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(Exception) });
            if (ci != null)
            {
                TException e = (TException)ci.Invoke(new object[] { message, innerException });
                throw e;
            }
            throw new TException();
        }
    }

    public static T NotNull<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return value;
    }

    public static string NotEmpty(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (value.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return value;
    }

    public static Guid NotEmpty(Guid value)
    {
        if (value == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return value;
    }

    public static T NotEmpty<T>(T value) where T : System.Collections.IEnumerable
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!value.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return value;
    }

    public static void IsEqual<T>(T a, T b) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (false == a.Equals(b))
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    public static void NotEqual<T>(T a, T b) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (true == a.Equals(b))
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    public static T[] ArraySize<T>(T[] value, int min, int max)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (value.Length < min || value.Length > max)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return value;
    }

    public static T InRange<T>(T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        return value;
    }

    public static T IsAssignable<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T)IsAssignable(typeof(T), value);
    }

    public static object IsAssignable(Type toType, object fromValue)
    {
        NotNull(toType);
        if (fromValue == null)
        {
            if (toType.IsValueType)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Can not set value of type {0} to null.", toType));
        }
        else
            IsAssignable(toType, fromValue.GetType());
        return fromValue;
    }

    public static void IsAssignable(Type toType, Type fromType)
    {
        if (!NotNull(toType).IsAssignableFrom(NotNull(fromType)))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Can not set value of type {0} to a value of type {1}", toType, fromType));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the file search that is slow and not your event handlers that get the results? Have you run it with the profiler?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you searching for? The code contains too many "distractions" so I can't spot the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Any reason why you didn't use managed APIs that are already provided, like `Systme.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles()` or `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries()`? It ends up calling the native API eventually, so I don't see any major performance gain by reinventing the wheel.